# GCC bug: 'X' is not a template?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Recently, I tested some template code on Codepad. Althought the code is correct, GCC is giving me a really strange error. I also tested it on Ideone:

Tested code:

```
template<int num>
struct count;

template<>
struct count<-1>
{
};

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

Here are the results, on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/h8xfcCBi) (GCC 4.1.2) and [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9Lbr7) (GCC 4.3.4) : GCC 4.1.2 outputs:

```
Line 5: error: 'count' is not a template
```

while GCC 4.3.4 compiles normally without errors.
Is this really a compiler bug, or is my code not correct (and compile thanks to extensions?)

Comment: Just to know, do you include STL + use namespace std? Because a std::count exists.

Comment: count with a lowercase "c" as a struct name is not a good programming practice

Comment: @MoatazElmasry: Says who? That's the convention used in many projects, including the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I don't have the problem with the gcc 4.1.2 I've here.

Comment: That's just a test, designed to work with C++03. And for gcc 4.1.2 : sometimes I like using codepad to test simple codes, and it is using gcc 4.1.2

Comment: @Mike Seymour. well for me its logical, but searching around for "c++ naming convention" I found both, so long discussion short, I find it more convient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I try

```
template<int num>
struct count;

template<>
struct count<-1>
{
};

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

with g++ 4.1.2, I don't have a problem.  If I try

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<int num>
struct count;

template<>
struct count<-1>
{
};

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

with g++ -Wfatal-errors I get

```
count.cpp:8: error: 'count' is not a template
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

So my guess is that Codepad is forcing a preamble on you which triggers the error.

Comment: It seems you've found the "error". Nice job! +1 +answer. It's definitely something that Codepad should show...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Codepad silently adds a bunch of `#include`s and a `using namespace std;` whether you want them or not: see [this example](http://codepad.org/xet06aXW) which shouldn't compile on its own:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

Output: Hello
```

This can break code like yours which defines a name (`count`) in the global namespace which also exists in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this error is a collision between identifier names.

Sometimes, one starts with a class. The class is extended into a template some time later. When there are still class prototypes around at this point (e.g. in a different header file), the compiler will issue this error.

(Although this does not apply to the specific case here, this answer it might help others who come accross this page during their search for help.)